# Why doesn't it cause an error when I set the length of a dim as zero

Tags: java, android

I think the follwoing code will cause error, but it works well in android, why?

`int[] myID=new int[0];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That just creates a zero-length array. That's absolutely fine - nothing wrong with it at all. It's an array with no elements. How else would you implement (say) a method which needs to return an array of "matching names" or something similar, but where there are no matches?

You'll get an error if you try to set or fetch any values in the array, but that's a different matter:

```
int[] empty = new int[0]; // This is fine
int firstElement = empty[0]; // This will throw an exception
```

The answer is not to do that...